# text inside span tag is not updated in my razor view after Ajax sucess

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, css-selectors

I have a span in my C# razor page which shows number of items ordered by user.

I receive the count of items after their update by reading response from ajax success and parts of my view are updated but some parts are not getting updated.

In my js code the update of div with id ="orderCount" is working but update of "food2" is not working.
Am I using wrong code for updating the span with id = "food2"?

P.S. Alert which is commented shows me the results are acceptable values when uncommented so it seems there is no problem with ajax response.
if (response.isSuccessful == true) {
//alert("Success: " + response.isSuccessful +
//    ", CartCount: " + response.totalCartItemsCount +
//    ", ItemCount: " + response.updatedFoodItemCount +
//    ", UpdatedFoodId: " + response.updatedFoodItemId);
$("#orderCount").text(response.totalCartItemsCount);
$("#food" + response.updatedFoodItemId).text(response.updatedFoodItemCount);
}

Here is my span:

```
<div class="row pt-3 pl-3">
    <div class="col-6"><span class="d-block font-12  text-success  overflow-dot"><span class="digit_divider">150,000</span> cents </span></div>
    <div class="col-6 text-left">
        <a onclick="increaseOrdereredFoodByOne('2')" class="beat-cart"><img src="/assets/icons/plus.svg" class="add-ico-width "></a>
        <span id="food2" class="font-16  color-orange px-1">1</span>
        <a onclick="decreaseOrdereredFoodByOne('2')" class="beat-cart"><img src="/assets/icons/minus.svg" class="add-ico-width "></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my complete ajax method:

```
function handleAjaxRequest(orderUpdate) {
    //alert('hello');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("AjaxUpdateOrder","Restaurants")",
        data: JSON.stringify(orderUpdate),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != null) {
            //isSuccessful = true,
            //totalCartItemsCount = totalCountOfItemsInOrder,
            //updatedFoodItemCount = countOfUpdatedItem,
            //updatedFoodItemId = foodId

                if (response.isSuccessful == true) {
                    //alert("Success: " + response.isSuccessful +
                    //    ", CartCount: " + response.totalCartItemsCount +
                    //    ", ItemCount: " + response.updatedFoodItemCount +
                    //    ", UpdatedFoodId: " + response.updatedFoodItemId);
                    $("#orderCount").text(response.totalCartItemsCount);
                    $("#food" + response.updatedFoodItemId).text(response.updatedFoodItemCount);
                } else {
                    if (response.notAllowedDueToOpenOrderInAnotherRestaurant == true) {
                        
                        showCollisionModal(response.errorPrompt);
                    } else {
                        //alert(response.errorPrompt);
                        showErrorPrompt(response.errorPrompt);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                        showErrorPrompt('some-error');
            }
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            

        },
        error: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you debug `$("#food" + response.updatedFoodItemId).text(response.updatedFoodItemCount);`,is `response.updatedFoodItemCount` right?And is `response.updatedFoodItemId` equals 2?I test with the following data,and it can work.
Here is a working demo:

View:

```
<div class="row pt-3 pl-3">
    <div class="col-6"><span class="d-block font-12  text-success  overflow-dot"><span class="digit_divider">150,000</span> cents </span></div>
    <div class="col-6 text-left">
        <a onclick="increaseOrdereredFoodByOne('2')" class="beat-cart"><img src="/assets/icons/plus.svg" class="add-ico-width "></a>
        <span id="food2" class="font-16  color-orange px-1">1</span>
        <a onclick="decreaseOrdereredFoodByOne('2')" class="beat-cart"><img src="/assets/icons/minus.svg" class="add-ico-width "></a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
        function decreaseOrdereredFoodByOne(orderUpdate) {
            handleAjaxRequest(orderUpdate);
        }
        function handleAjaxRequest(orderUpdate) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("AjaxUpdateOrder","Test1")",
        data: JSON.stringify(orderUpdate),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != null) {


                if (response.isSuccessful == true) {

                    $("#food" + response.updatedFoodItemId).text(response.updatedFoodItemCount);
                } else {
                    if (response.notAllowedDueToOpenOrderInAnotherRestaurant == true) {

                        showCollisionModal(response.errorPrompt);
                    } else {

                        showErrorPrompt(response.errorPrompt);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                        showErrorPrompt('some-error');
            }
        },
        failure: function(response) {


        },
        error: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
    </script>
```

Test1Controller:

```
public IActionResult AjaxUpdateOrder([FromBody] string orderUpdate) {
            Object1 O = new Object1 { isSuccessful = true, totalCartItemsCount = 10, updatedFoodItemId = 2 , updatedFoodItemCount =3};
            return Json(O);
        }
```

Object1:

```
public class Object1 {
        public bool isSuccessful { get; set; }
        public int totalCartItemsCount { get; set; }
        public int updatedFoodItemId { get; set; }
        public int updatedFoodItemCount { get; set; }
        public bool notAllowedDueToOpenOrderInAnotherRestaurant { get; set; }
        public string errorPrompt { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]